# how to remove records when orderid is repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
OrderId   InvoiceNumber  LocationId
1          A1             1
1          B1             2
1                         0
2                         0
3          C1             2
3                         0
```

**Expected Output**

```
OrderId   InvoiceNumber  LocationId
1          A1             1
1          B1             2
2                         0
3          C1             2
```

In above Result....i want to remove those recored which have InvoiceNumber is null and LocationId is 0 when orderId is repeated in query.

In above Example....OrderId=1 record is repeated so then check InvoiceNuber is null and LocationId is 0  if found then removed it

OrderId=2 is not repeated so keep the record....

I tried this

```
Select * from tblName where isnull(InvoiceNuber,'')='' and LocationId=0
```

But...this query is wrong...

Thank uuu...!!..

Comment: Should gaps be considered? Is it considered a repeated sequence only if if the records align next to each other or would anywhere in the results set also be a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, count(InvoiceNumber) over(partition by orderId) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where not (InvoiceNumber is null and locationId = 0 and cnt > 0)
```

This evicts rows where `InvoiceNumber` is `null` and `locationId` is `0` for which another row exists with the same `orderId` and a non-`null` `InvoiceNumber`.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh: sorry, it was missing a surrounding `not` in the `where` clause. Fixed.

Comment: sir it showing all the reocrds.......not expected output..

Comment: @AkhileshSingh: for your sample data, this produces the results you showed, as you can see **[in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6263b837607774097cbe94663484ff54)**.

Comment: sir if we use blank space('') instead of null ...it totally showing different result...

Comment: @AkhileshSingh: of course, if you change the sample data, the results are different... If you want spaces instead of `null`s, use `InvoiceNumber = ''` instead of `InvoiceNumber is null` in the `where` clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216967/discussion-between-akhilesh-singh-and-gmb).